# Python return to line above for writing

Tags: python

How can I make python program return to the start of output area after writing 4 lines of data. For example Program outputs fields 1....field 4 in different lines,after this program wants to add some data to line of field 1 ,but output is coming on line 5. The program is for converting data into tabular form.

Comment: You can `seek` a file pointer, but if you are printing to the console, no, you can't do this

Comment: Maybe a better option for you is to build all your lists of data as rows, then print them all accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to a file, you can use the `seek()` function to relocate the file pointer wherever you want. For example, `f.seek(0,0)` will take you to the beginning of the file and then you can output the next data item there. However, keep in mind that you'll need to first move the data that you already wrote to the file, otherwise it will be over-written; that is, you need to "make space" for the new data you want to write to the beginning of the file.

For a quick intro, see https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html, near the bottom of the page.